# How to export data from multiple sheets in old Excel file into one sheet in new Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

im trying to export excel file that contain multiple sheets, and each sheets have a data (maybe from 50-70 rows).

Well in the old excel file, it contain around 169 sheets so when you multiply 169 and 50 it will contain 8450 rows in the new Excel file

But when i try to execute the code, the result will only contain 500 rows.
This is the code im trying

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\Documents\\testFile.xlsm"); 
            string full = fileInfo.DirectoryName + "\\testResult.xlsx"; //Location for new Excel file that contain the result

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Documents\\testFile.xlsm");//Open the file
            xlWS = xlWb.Sheets[xlWb.Sheets.Count];//Count the sheets
            xlApp1 = new Excel.Application();
            xlWb1 = xlApp1.Workbooks.Add();
            int roww;//variable to save last number of row in the new excel file


            for (int i = 2; i <xlWb.Sheets.Count; i++) // looping
            {
                xlWb.Sheets[i].Activate();
                xlRange = xlWS.UsedRange;
                row = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                col = xlRange.Columns.Count;


                xlWS1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWb1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                xlRange1 = xlWS1.UsedRange;
                roww = xlRange1.Rows.Count;
                fulldata = new string[row][];
                //for transfer data to temp variable
                for (int j = 0; j < fulldata.Length; j++)
                {
                    fulldata[j] = new string[col];

                }
                for(int k = 0 ; k<row;k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < col; l++)
                    {
                        fulldata[k][l] = xlWS.Cells[k + 1, l + 1].value2.ToString();
                    }
                }
                //too export the data
                if (roww == 1) //if to count how many roww there is in the new file, if there is no data then it just put the data from the first row
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k <row; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < col; l++)
                        {
                            xlWS1.Cells[k + 1, l + 1] = fulldata[k][l];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else // if the file contain data from last sheet *means there will be more than 1 rows already fiiled
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < row; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < col; l++)
                        {
                            xlWS1.Cells[roww + 1, l + 1] = fulldata[k][l];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xlWb.Save();
            xlWb.Close();
            xlWb1.SaveAs(full, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, missing, missing,
            false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            xlWb1.Close();
            closeExcel(xlApp);
            closeExcel(xlApp1);
}
```

The expected result is the  result will have 8450 rows which contain data from multiple sheets that i want to export

The actual results is only 500 rows, maybe someone can correct my code, i dont know what do i miss here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above, within the `for` loop, within the `else` block (where you are adding values in the case when sheet in new excel already has some data)

you are setting:

```
xlWS1.Cells[roww + 1, l + 1] = fulldata[k][l];
```

Here, you are not incrementing the row value for the `Cells` property. Since `roww` will contain same data during the execution of the `for` loop, you are always going to write the data in the same row.

Here it should be

```
xlWS1.Cells[roww + k + 1, l + 1] = fulldata[k][l];
```